# Why is apache matching a String twice instead of once in a RewriteRule?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a RewriteRule in the htaccess applied which should match exactly that sort of string: `01,02,03,04` and append it to the url as a GET param like `&option=$2`. But instead he matches `01,02,03,04`, appends it as `$option=$2`and than matches `04` again and appends it as `$otheroption=$3`. What am I missing here?

```
RewriteRule  ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(([0-9]{2}[,]?)+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /index.php?site=$1&content=$2&objektart=$3&vermarktungsart=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You might want to edit your question as the expected and actual results seem to be the same. Also please add example URLs for input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double brackets in `(([0-9]{2}[,]?)+)` so that part catches your third argument twice. You can either use the 5th result from set instead of the 4th or even better use a non-capturing group. Since you only want to create a character class here, a non-capturing group is the way to go:

```
RewriteRule  ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/((?:[0-9]{2}[,]?)+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /index.php?site=$1&content=$2&objektart=$3&vermarktungsart=$4
```

Note the `?:` at the beginning of the inner brackets. This means the contents is considered a group but does not apply to the result set.

For the input

```
aaa/bbb/3333/ccc
```

this would produce the output

```
/index.php?site=aaa&content=bbb&objektart=3333&vermarktungsart=ccc
```

Comment: But if I make it like this `([0-9]{2}[,]?)+` only the last number gets caught.

Comment: Updated the answer for non-capturing groups which you seem to need here.

Comment: Nice. I think this is what I missed here. Thanks for bringing that up. As it is more elegant I will go with that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution `([0-9,]{2,})` but still I think the one above should make it as well...